Error while swapping solana token: TypeError: pubkey.toBase58 is not a function
   async getSwapTransaction(
     toToken: string,
     amount: number,
     poolKeys: LiquidityPoolKeys,
     useVersionedTransaction: boolean = true,
     fixedSide: 'in' | 'out' = 'in',
   ): Promise<Transaction | VersionedTransaction> {

     const directionIn = poolKeys.quoteMint.toString() == toToken

     const { minAmountOut, amountIn } = await this.calcAmountOut(poolKeys, amount, directionIn);    

     const userTokenAccounts = await this.getOwnerTokenAccounts();

     const publicKey = new PublicKey(this.wallet.publicKey);

     const swapTransaction = await Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple({
       connection: this.connection,
       makeTxVersion: useVersionedTransaction ? 0 : 1,
       poolKeys: {
         ...poolKeys,
       },
       userKeys: {
         tokenAccounts: userTokenAccounts,
         owner: publicKey,
       },
       amountIn: amountIn,
       amountOut: minAmountOut,
       fixedSide: fixedSide,
       config: {
         bypassAssociatedCheck: false,
       },
       computeBudgetConfig: {
        microLamports: config.swapConfig.maxLamports
       }
     })

    const recentBlockhashForSwap = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash()

    const instructions = swapTransaction.innerTransactions[0].instructions.filter(Boolean)

     if (useVersionedTransaction) {  
        const versionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(
          new TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: recentBlockhashForSwap.blockhash,
            instructions: instructions,
          }).compileToV0Message()
        );

        versionedTransaction.sign([this.wallet.payer]);
        return versionedTransaction;
    } else {
      console.error("Use versioned transaction is false");
    }
 
     const legacyTransaction = new Transaction({
       blockhash: recentBlockhashForSwap.blockhash,
       lastValidBlockHeight: recentBlockhashForSwap.lastValidBlockHeight,
       feePayer: publicKey,
     })
 
     legacyTransaction.add(...instructions)
 
     return legacyTransaction
   }


When I am trying to run the swap its giving me an error of pubkey.toBase58 is not a function since its working fine for any existing token in solana just for the new pairs I have this issue coming.

double-check the addresses, such as the pool address, base token address, and quote token address. This error commonly occurs when incorrect addresses are passed.
